# testng and gradle - see output from deadlocked tests?

Tags: testng, gradle

If I have a test that hangs I don't seem to get any results.

Is there any way to see output live?

Thank you
Misha

Answer (score 1):

Ok I still have no idea how to formally do this but I just redirected standard output and error:

```
/**
 * Redirect standard output and error to appropriate files
 */
public void redirectStandardOutputAndErrorToFiles(className) {
  def outFile=new   File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")+File.separator+className+".out.log")
  if (outFile.exists()) {
    outFile.delete()
  }
  def errFile=new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")+File.separator+className+".err.log")
  if (errFile.exists()) {
    errFile.delete()
  }
  def out=new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile))
  def err=new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(errFile))
  System.setOut(out)
  System.setErr(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following directive to the test task to tell it to output the standard streams:

`build.gradle:`

```
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```